# Why is Excel VBA Row Height not equal to Range Height

Tags: excel, vba

The following two methods are returning different results and I'm trying to understand what the relationship is.

Method 1:
I manually set the row height by right clicking on the row. I sum up the height of a few of these rows to get a total height of a range of rows.

Method 2:
I use the Range.Height property in VBA to get the total height of that set of rows.

If I simplify my range to just a single row, this will be different in cases where the manual row height is not a multiple of 3, but the relationship does not appear to be linear.

Code to get range height:

```
Sub range_height()
    MsgBox Range("A1").Height
End Sub
```

Set row 1 height = 15 and range_height returns a message box of 15.

Set row 1 height = 20 and range_height returns a message box of 19.5.

My ultimate goal is to be able to add padding to a range so that when I copy into PowerPoint, I have identical dimensions and my slides are pleasant to look at. I can do this via trial and error, but I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Your procedure `range_height` always shows exactly what I manually adjusted the row to. If I select 100 rows of the same height then `Range("A1:A100").Height` shows 100 times the height of one row. Works perfectly here. • No offence, but could it be that you use a touchpad on a notebook to manually set the height and therefore you are not able to set it so correctly?

Comment: No offense taken, but that isn't my issue. I'm on a laptop using peripheral keyboard and mouse using Excel 365. Did you test various heights and get the right number every time? I'm trying to think of what could impact this in my instance.

Comment: Instead of setting the height manually, why not try it programmatically?

Comment: I'm formatting tables which will end up on a PowerPoint slide. There is an identically formatted summary table which must appear in the same position, but different information exists on each as well. It takes some manual formatting to make each item look nicely, but the extra distance is the variable I need to control for. I could try, but it introduces a lot more complexity and loses flexibility.

Comment: @ackshooairy Yes, I tried various heights, always exactly the same. The only thing I can imagine is that you moved the mouse one pixel while you released the mouse button. What is your ratio between pixels and height? If I set height 10 this makes 20 pixels (I think this changes with screen resolution). Since you can manually set only full pixels (because your mouse can only move full pixels) the issue might be in here.

Comment: I wonder if it could be due to screen resolution, but it can't be the way you're describing. I'm entering the height by right clicking the row, choosing "row height" and typing it in. If I do that again to check, it is the value I typed. Then I run the procedure and I get a different number.

Comment: @ackshooairy well that is the problem. Screenresolution or better DPI matters. If you enter 20 that cannot be converted into `Integer` pixels (but the height can only be in full pixels). Try to set 20 by mouse (not with the row height dialog) and you will probably see 20 cannot be reached (it jumps over it) but 19.5

Comment: You are exactly right. 19.5 = 26 pixels and 20.5 = 27 pixels. I'm on a 1920x1200 monitor. I suppose the easiest solution is either to adjust my resolution or to figure out how to set the row and columns in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem while trying to draw lines in excel using VBA. I was using range.top and range.height for deriving the co-ordinates for my work. However, lines were getting drawn at slightly offset location than expected. Further I found that offset was varying with varying row sizes…
Finally I figured out that for row height =15, row height and range height were matching.
So, I changed all row height to 15, created my lines using VBA and then changed the row height as per requirement. Lines location was now matching my requirement!